# Sbt : multi task ordering

Tags: scala, sbt, task

I want to make tasks dependent on each other in sbt. I want task `task2` to execute before `task3`.
Here's my code :

```
Task1.dependsOn(task3)
Task3.dependsOn(task2)
```

`task2` executes before `task3` and then `task1` is executed.
Now If I use this:

```
Task1.dependsOn(task2, task3)
```

Does sbt preserve order of tasks? So that execution order is 2 3 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The answer is no. It does not preserve order. Let's examine this.

I created a simple `build.sbt` containing:

```
val task1 = taskKey[Seq[String]]("taks1")
val task2 = taskKey[Seq[String]]("taks2")
val task3 = taskKey[Seq[String]]("taks3")

task1 := {
  println("task1")
  Seq("111")
}

task2 := {
  println("task2")
  Seq("222")
}

task3 := {
  println("task3")
  Seq("333")
}
```

Then adding:

```
task1 := task1.dependsOn(task2, task3).value
```

When running `sbt task1` I get consistently the output:

```
task2
task3
task1
```

This might cause you to think that the later is the first one to execute. It is only partially true. Let's remember that those actions are asynchronous. Let's add some sleeps and prints. Let's modify `task2`(which supposed to be printed first):

```
task2 := {
  println("task2 started")
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  println("task2 finished")
  Seq("222")
}
```

Then running `task1` provide:

```
task2 started
task3
task2 finished
task1
```

Which proves that they don't preserve order. If you do want to preserve order, there are many ways to achieve that. For example:

```
task1 := task1.dependsOn(task3).dependsOn(task2).value
```

which outputs:

```
task2 started
task2 finished
task3
task1
```

Or:

```
task1 := task1.dependsOn(task3).value
task1 := task1.dependsOn(task2).value
```

Which outputs the same. Or you can even declare `task2` as a dependency of `task3`:

```
task1 := task1.dependsOn(task3).value
task3 := task3.dependsOn(task2).value
```

Which outputs the same. Before taking a decision, you might want to read [Task graph](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Task-Graph.html#Defining+a+task+that+depends+on+other+settings) and [Scope delegation (.value lookup)](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scope-Delegation.html).